# Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=48 "Address already in use" Error in bind() function1

Tags: ios, swift3

Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=48 "Address already in use" Error in bind() function

Comment: Please provide some more information to have some idea about what is happening here next time. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
class DeviceScanning:NSObject,GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate{
    
    var address = "255.255.255.255"
    var port:UInt16 = 5593
    var socket:GCDAsyncUdpSocket!
    var socketReceive:GCDAsyncUdpSocket!
    var error : NSError?
    
     override init() {
    }
    
    func broadcastNearByDevices(){
        let jsnStr = "{\"cmd\":\"ping\"}"
        let message = jsnStr.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        socket = GCDAsyncUdpSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
        do {
            try socket.enableReusePort(true)
            try socket.bind(toPort: port)
            try socket.enableBroadcast(true)
            try socket.beginReceiving()
            socket.send(message!, toHost: address, port: port, withTimeout: -1, tag: 0)
        } catch {
            stopBroadcasting()
            print(error)
            //delegate?.broadcastData(ipAddress: error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    func stopBroadcasting(){
        socket?.close()
    }
    private func udpSocket(sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket!, didConnectToAddress address: NSData!) {
        print("didConnectToAddress");
    }
    
    private func udpSocket(sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket!, didNotConnect error: NSError!) {
        print("didNotConnect \(error)")
    }
    
    func udpSocket(_ sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket!, didSendDataWithTag tag: Int) {
        print("didSendDataWithTag")
    }
    
    private func udpSocket(sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket!, didNotSendDataWithTag tag: Int, dueToError error: NSError!) {
        print("didNotSendDataWithTag")
    }
    
    func udpSocket(_ sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket, didReceive data: Data, fromAddress address: Data,withFilterContext filterContext: Any?) {
        //smartDevicesArr.removeAll()
        var host: NSString?
        var port1: UInt16 = 0
        
        GCDAsyncUdpSocket.getHost(&host, port: &port1, fromAddress: address as Data)
        print("From",data)
        
        let gotdata: NSString = NSString(data: data as Data as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
        print("gotdata",gotdata)
        
       if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:Any] {
print("JSON Response is",json)
}
    }
}
```

Comment: Same for the answer. What problem is it solving? Some context would be very appreciated.